# pass tcp client object to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, tcp, android-activity

I am building an app that uses tcp. I need to pass the tcp client object (after connected to the server) to another activity. I.e. I have an activity called Join that searchs for a host, allows the client to connect, and then Join will finish cand start a new activity (GameActivity). I need to some how pass the client object to the GameActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach in your case would be to create the tcp connection in a Singleton class, this way you can have access to your connection in a simple maner, [here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2013/03/android-tcp-connection-enhanced.html) is a sample code. Also a better idea would be to use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) component from android.

Comment: i think you are right. i have gone with the singleton class. it makes more sense, but i was being lazy